# Git on windows - cannot push to remote repository using the local (file) protocol

Tags: windows, git

I am using Git version 1.9.2-preview20140411 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64.

When I try to push to a remote repository using the local (file) protocol, I get the error:

> fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
$ cat PushTestCase.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace

cd /C/work/Git
git init --bare MyProjectBare
git clone MyProjectBare MyProjectClone
cd MyProjectClone
echo "apples, oranges" > fruit.txt
git add fruit.txt
git commit -a -m "First commit"
git push orgin master
git remote -v
git remote show orgin

$ PushTestCase.sh
+ cd /C/work/Git
+ git init --bare MyProjectBare
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/work/Git/MyProjectBare/
+ git clone MyProjectBare MyProjectClone
Cloning into 'MyProjectClone'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.
+ cd MyProjectClone
+ echo 'apples, oranges'
+ git add fruit.txt
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in fruit.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
+ git commit -a -m 'First commit'
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in fruit.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master (root-commit) 74ee22d] First commit
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in fruit.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 fruit.txt
+ git push orgin master
fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
+ git remote -v
origin  c:/work/Git/MyProjectBare (fetch)
origin  c:/work/Git/MyProjectBare (push)
+ git remote show orgin
fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$
```

Originally I tried this with the remote repository on a network drive.  In order to eliminate any possible permission issues, I've reproduced the problem using a remote repository on a local drive.

I know another option is to setup SSH on the server, but I would much rather get this working using the local protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has a typo.  Correct:

```
git push orgin master
```

to:

```
git push origin master
```